# Layer from PostGIS with array of integers fields?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have GeoServer 2.6 and I published a vector layer (point) which some of the field attributes are integer's array.

GeoServer doesn't recognize those fields in wfs call or even in the Feature Type details table.

Is there any possibility to give them visibility?

I need to symbolize that points taking in account those fields.

Comment: Probably not an ideal solution but have a try by making a view where you cast the list array into string. I fear that queries into this string attribute can fail. Can the list be very long? A short list I would explode to normal attributes: attr1, attr2, attr3...

Comment: Thanks for the comment I thought to do that if geoserver doesn't support those kind of fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the view, the only other possibility that comes to mind is to teach GeoServer to recognize these fields by improving its code. You can ask on the geotools-devel/geoserver-devel mailing list for directions, if you plan to do it yourself, or check the commercial support links at geotools.org and geoserver.org