# Using PostgreSQL Array Data in GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, array

I'm working to setup GeoServer on a table, and ran into a new issue where one of my fields is a [PostgreSQL Array of type text[]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) that stores tags.  I'd like to be able to use and query that field in GeoServer similar to `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'Tag' = ALL (my_tags);` but GeoServer does not recognize the array text[] field.

Is there something I can do to get that field into GeoServer, or is there a recommended alternative, as I've only seen some older questions on SO like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123504/layer-from-postgis-with-array-of-integers-fields) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306456/how-should-arrays-be-stored-in-postgresql-when-used-as-a-datastore-with-geoserve)?

Comment: Array to String? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html

Comment: adding to @Mapperz suggestion - `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'Tag' = ALL (string_to_array(my_tags,','))` or `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_tags LIKE '%Tag%'`

Comment: as far as I know this answer is still the case - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123510/79